# Group and sum multiple columns using power query

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, powerquery

I'm newbee to PQ, but I have a task to do.
I would appreciate the help if it will be provided)

I have the following table:

| YEAR | MONTH | ID | Option | Q_1 | Q_2 | ... | Q_100 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | JANUARY | 1111 | plan | 23452 | 23105 | ... | 549 |
| 2020 | JANUARY | 1111 | plan | 23453 | 23106 | ... | 530 |
| 2020 | JANUARY | 1111 | plan | 23454 | 23107 | ... | 510 |
| 2020 | JANUARY | 1111 | fact | 34689 | 33000 | ... | 467 |
| 2020 | JANUARY | 1111 | fact | 34690 | 33010 | ... | 477 |
| 2020 | JANUARY | 1111 | fact | 34691 | 33020 | ... | 488 |
| 2020 | JANUARY | 1111 | fact | 34692 | 33045 | ... | 490 |

I need to group table by first 4 columns and sum the value from columns starting with "Q"

So, the output should be:

| YEAR | MONTH | ID | Option | Profile | SUM of every match |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | JANUARY | 1111 | plan | Q_1 | 70359 |
| 2020 | JANUARY | 1111 | plan | Q_2 | 69138 |
| 2020 | JANUARY | 1111 | plan | ... | ... |
| 2020 | JANUARY | 1111 | plan | Q_100 | 1589 |
| 2020 | JANUARY | 1111 | fact | Q_1 | 138762 |
| 2020 | JANUARY | 1111 | fact | Q_2 | 132075 |
| 2020 | JANUARY | 1111 | fact | ... | ... |
| 2020 | JANUARY | 1111 | fact | Q_100 | 1922 |

For sure, Year, Month and ID have more option than 1; Option has more options than 2.

Comment: thanks for posting data as data instead of as an image!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unpivot, then group, as follows

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"YEAR", "MONTH", "ID", "Option"}, "Profile", "Value"),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"YEAR", "MONTH", "ID", "Option", "Profile"}, {{"SUM of every match", each List.Sum([Value]), type number}})
in  #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]

[image]